# Proving existance by providing an example

Tags: coq, proof

If i have a Theorem of the form:

```
Theorem my_thm (n: nat -> nat): exists t: nat, n t = 0.
Admitted.
```

If I want to prove it for a function that is such that `my_func 0 = 0`, how can I tell coq that indeed there exists such t because my_func 0 = 0 ?

This does not have a deep goal but understand how existential proof works in coq.

Comment: Your theorem is about all functions of type nat->nat. There are lots of such functions that never have value 0.

Comment: What if I want to use this theorem for a specific function ?

Comment: You are mistaking `Theorem`s for `Definition`s. What you have done is *positing the truth of* the logical proposition `∀ (n : nat → nat), ∃ (t : nat), n t = 0`. What you really want to do is to *define* a logical predicate over values `n : nat → nat`, i.e. a function that maps its argument `n : nat → nat` to a proposition (independently of it being proven or not). `Definition my_pred (n : nat → nat) := ∃ (t : nat), n t = 0.` Then `my_pred` is a function of type `(nat → nat) → Prop`, and `my_pred my_fun` is a proposition. You can declare, and prove, a theorem asserting the truth of that prop.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an argument, here `P`, that would assert that this property holds, and use it later on in your theorem, using the `exists` tactic. For instance (I'm using ssreflect, but I guess you'll get the idea):

```
Theorem my_thm (n: nat -> nat) (P : n 0 = 0) : exists u, n u = 0.
Proof.
exists 0.
exact: P.
Qed.
```

Of course, you can also change the theorem body to better suit your needs.